# Pyramid Pserve, how to close socket without closing terminal?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm learning about pyramid at the moment but am having an issue with the socket staying in use if I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to exit pserve while it's hosting locally (there's actually a python process that keeps running even after I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to shut down pserve). If I try to run pserve again I get an error that says

> [Errno 48] Address already in use

The only way to fix this is to quit right out of the terminal and restart with a fresh terminal, which means re-activating my virtual environment every time.

It's just a bit of a hassle and I want to be able to stop pserve and any other apps/packages that pyramid runs without having to exit the terminal and re-activate the virtual environment every time I make a change. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise your question:

- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** requests to **kill** your program with signal `SIGINT`.
- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** forces the program to **suspend and go into the background** with signal `SIGSTP`.

When a process is suspended you can resume it, but you cannot resume a killed process.

In your case, you should use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if you want to **kill** your socket process.

Notes:

- You can view the suspended processes by using `jobs` command
- If you need to know more about handling background processes you can
  refer to this
  [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job)

Comment: oh wow, I didn't know that; I thought that CTRL+ Z killed it. So it was a problem with me not knowing the terminal hotkeys, thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @KyleK Glad it helped to understand the difference. Please mark it as the accepted answer if it helped :)